# Why use Routing in PHP?

Tags: php

Or any language for that matter. I’m new to using routes, learning them via Laravel.

Just wondering why not just use links? Aside from prettier URLs. Just more options as to what happens when you visit a URL or what?

When I think of going to the about page for example I think about clicking a navigation item. Why use routing to do the same thing?

Comment: It means you don't have to write separate scripts for each operation, you can do it using the routing framework.

Comment: @Barmar And what do you mean by “each operation”. I write PHP daily, but not sure what you mean. You may have oversimplified it.

Comment: I thought that's what you meant by "why not just use links". E.g. `update.php`, `delete.php`, etc. instead of `script.php/update`, `script.php/delete`, etc. and then routing with Laravel inside `script.php`.

Comment: @Barmar oh lol, no. I meant navigation sorry I’ll update. Why use routing instead of site navigation? Or am I ruining about it wrong?

Comment: Are you asking why to implement the application as a Single Page Application rather than linking to different pages?

Comment: @Barmar wow. Maybe I am. I think you just opened a gateway to my learning. I think I was thinking about it wrong. Creating a static website for example, always uses navigation that takes you to multiple pages. I guess the answer is, if I want to do multiple things while on ONE page (SPA) then I would use routing?

Comment: You could, but there are other ways to do it. Routing is part of some frameworks designed for implementing SPAs.

Comment: Try to implement what you have in mind first. Your understanding of how web works is probably a little fuzzy at the moment.

Comment: @zerkms maybe I am explaining it wrong. I have been developing professionally for two years. I just worked at a small company and never used frameworks. I just got hired at a new place where they use Laravel so I am trying to understand the purpose of routing. But I wouldn’t say I don’t understand how the web works. More accurately, the web works in many different ways and not everyone understands all the ways.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can implement anything in web without some sort of "routing". The request should be routed somewhere according some rules.

Comment: @zerkms So that is the other half of what my question was. A navigation bar with links would technically be considered routing, correct? If so, what is the purpose of routing in terms how Laravel (and possible other frameworks) implement it?

Comment: "A navigation bar with links would technically be considered routing, correct?" - nope. "routing" is a server-side concept. "what is the purpose of routing in terms how Laravel" --- exactly the same as everywhere in web: to provide an entry point that handles a request.

Comment: @zerkms That is what I am getting at man! Method A: You click a link it goes to a page (obviously stored on the server). Method B: You setup a Route (Laravel style or whatever) and decide what happens when the user reaches that page. What is the difference?

Comment: @KevinMarmet what you said makes little sense to me :-S Every request is routed somewhere, regardless.

Comment: I don’t understand what doesn’t make sense. Also, not sure how that is relevant. Not disputing that every request is routed. I’m asking what is the difference in the two methods. I’m NEW to manually creating routes as Laravel does it and I am trying to figure out why it is done that way. Whether I setup a route that handles what happens when a user goes to the about page or whether the user clicks and link which takes them to the about page and then a script runs, I don’t see the difference. If that example doesn’t make sense than never mind.

Comment: "A wise man's question contains half the answer". "which takes them to the about page" --- now have a look at the url for this very page and say - do you really believe `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808042/why-use-routing-in-php` - this path physically exists on the server?